# Fuzzy search page for an online travel agency

Tags: interaction-design, search, filter, user-centered-design, travel

I'm building the search page for an OTA (online travel agency). The brief has a few quirks that make this task difficult, so I need some help to identify some feasible ideas.

Most OTAs have a "standard" interface with a form asking for dates, places, and the number of rooms or travelers. Then they return a list on the right with a large number of filters available on the left.

This has a number of disadvantages:

- one needs to know a number of exact pieces of data in order to search
- filters are complex and highly useful criteria go mixed with marginally useful ones
- there is *almost no space* for fuzzy, imprecise criteria such as "I want to travel one of the next weekends" or "I want to go to Europe with my girlfriend for less than 500 Euro"
- it's almost impossible to book trips, which have multiple parts (e.g. hotels, transports, airplane, activities...) unless they are pre-made packages on offer.

What I need to build needs to:

- allow for fuzzy and incomplete criteria
- allow for complex queries involving different flights for different people, for example, total budget, and other complex requirements
- not to be a fixed form like other OTAs
- not to be a textbox where one writes their wishes and magically a result appears.

What is normally considered best practice to allow the gathering of fuzzy, imprecise, or incomplete requirements from a user in a website or mobile?

Comment: I recommend you pare down your question. As it stands, it's reads to me like, "What is the best practice for building a site that's better than Expedia, and with only one search box?" Are you asking about which technology to employ to start with a sentence and provide the user travel recommendations? That's incredibly complex, but it's a more answerable question (which could be NLP, Google it ;) When you figure out how to get to Europe with your girlfriend for less than 500 €, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I think 'fuzzy' search is a term that was used when natural language processing wasn't as mature as it is now. But I suspect that you are looking at having to come up with a simpler problem to solve, or to spend the time and effort in creating a more sophisticated solution. It all comes down to time and $...

I suggest looking at [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) and their examples of [Natural Language Processing](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/natural-language-processing/) capabilities as to how they manage the expressions that can be used as input and how it is processed.

There are probably other examples as well but I think this is an area that they seem to specialise in and has been successful in creating proper context for different types of searches.